# How to find an element in a binary search tree?

Tags: c++, find

I've been trying to build a 2-3 node. The adding function is working properly and has been confirmed by me so far. The only problem is the find function, which is called to find an element inside the 2-3 node. It does not seem to be working at all. The match pointer inside the it does not take the returned valued from the `find_rec` method at all, even though I already assigned it. It's just getting a new given address whenever the function is called and I have no idea why it does that. Can anyone help me out ? and tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you

```
**LValue and RValue**

E LValue() {return _first._value;}
E RValue() {return _second._value;}



**find function**

// Assuming this set contains an element y such that (x == y),
// return a reference to y. Such a y must exist; if it does not an
// assertion will fail. 
E& find(E& x) 
{
        // the match pointer is supposed to take
        // returned pointer from the find_rec function
        // Yet, it is not doing that at all.
    E* match = find_rec(x, _root);
    assert(match != nullptr);
    return *match;
}


**find_rec function**

// Helper function: find recursion
// function returns a pointer
E* find_rec(E& x, BNode<E>* root)
{
    if(root == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    else
    {
        // 2-node
        if(!root->IsThree())
        {
            if(x == root->LValue())
                return &root->LValue();
            else if (x < root->LValue())
                return find_rec(x, root->GetLeft());
            else
                return find_rec(x, root->GetRight());
        }
        // 3-node
        else
        {
            if(x == root->LValue())
                return &root->LValue();
            else if(x == root->RValue())
                return &root->RValue();
            else if(x < root->LValue())
                return find_rec(x, root->GetLeft());
            else if(x < root->RValue())
                return find_rec(x, root->GetMiddle());
            else
                return find_rec(x, root->GetRight());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RichardPlunkett: it looks correct to me as well, but it's not working as intended :(

Comment: those names starting with underscores  bother me. Didn't C++ reserve those quite sometime ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is clearly able to return a nullptr when the desired value is not present in the tree.

The moment it gets into that situation, the assert will trigger and the `*match` return would fail. I expect you need to change the function signature to provide a return type that allows for this case.

Answer (score 1):

From the code seems you're returning the address of a local temporary.

I cannot be sure because the `LValue()` method declaration is not visible, but if it's returning the node content by value and not by reference then the `find_rec` function will just return garbage (the address of a temporary allocated on the stack).

A decent compiler should issue a warning for this, by the way.

Comment: I just edit my post and put up the RValue and LValue. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and it compiles successfully without any warnings at all. The program runs, but it crashes right at the assert checking, because matching is pointing to NULL....

Comment: As I suspected `LValue` and `RValue` are returning by value and the code would not work (and if VS2012 doesn't issue a warning about returning the address of a local it simply means VS2012 is not a decent compiler). If the function is returning `NULL` then the tree doesn't contain what you think or is not respecting the order invariant. Can't tell what the problem is without seeing all the code.

Comment: The tree does have the value, and the insert function is working properly as well. It's just that I cannot link the pointer to the value of the node in the find function.

Comment: If the result is `nullptr` then you're not finding the node. If instead you are finding the node then using `&root->LValue()` is wrong, because the result is a temporary and you should not return the address of a temporary to the caller (once you're back in the caller the temporary doesn't exist any more). To get this last part working you can just change `LValue()` and `RValue()` to return `E&` instead of `E`.

Comment: definitely should fix this. I encourage returning a reference.